Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502 () after upgrade ssh server
I made a stupid decision to run do-release-upgrade in ubuntu ssh server and after that, the website is not working.
It didn't show the tabs on top after upgrade and reboot of server, it gives this error:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502 ()
https://siteurl/api/auth/permissions?email=myemail

502 Bad Gateway
nginx/1.15.12


When I tried to manually go to one of the route (for example, siteurl/finance), it gives another error:
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: NG04002
Error: NG04002
The code is the same as before, and it works fine when running development server in localhost.
I noticed that I can't roll back the upgrade, where should I start troubleshooting?
(Tried to restart the portainers, they are running fine.)

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
